# Lenovo ThinkCentre M92p DisplayPort to HDMI - no screen

Tags: lenovo, hdmi, displayport

I'm trying to build a media centre out of a ThinkCentre M92p using Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop and I've confirmed that the DisplayPort output works, but when I try to use a DP to HDMI adapter I don't get a signal, although it worked when the machine had Windows on it.

Any recommendations on what might be the issue?